# Filters and the Neighborhood System at a Point

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $x \in X$. Prove that the intersection of all filters on $X$ converging to $x \in X$, say $\mathscr{F}_x$, is precisely the neighborhood system $\mathscr{N}_x$ at $x$.
I have been able to show only $\mathscr{N}_x$ is subset of $\mathscr{F}_x$.
But how to show the reverse inclusion.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that the neighbourhood system $\mathscr{N}_x$ is itself a filter converging to $x \in X$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: How to prove that , a space is compact iff each ultranet in it converges.I will be happy if you give me any hint .

Comment: @Mathisbeautiful That is not within my expertise. I suggest you ask a new question so that someone else can help out.

Comment: Actually I cannot ask any question more .what should I do?

Comment: @Mathisbeautiful An ultranet (universal net) converges to any cluster point. Every net has a subnet that's an ultranet. It now is easy if you know compactness is equivalent to every net has a cluster point. See my note http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/13.pdf